# Как скрыть определенное слово в тексте без добавления нового тега?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня есть код:

`<div>Lorem ispum custom test</div`

Я хотел бы только спрятать, но не удалять   слово `custom` без добавления нового тега.

Как я могу это сделать?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Hide specific word in a text without add new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64858774/7394871) от участника  [@Jackom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12963227/jackom).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64858774/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать `mask` или `clip-path`. Обратите внимание, что это не надежное решение, поскольку вам нужно настроить значение на основе свойств шрифта и реального текста:

```css
.box {
  /* the text to hide start at 90px and end at 137px */
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(to right,#fff 90px,transparent 0 137px,#fff 0)
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Lorem ispum custom test</div>
```

Или использовать `clip-path`:

```css
.box {
  /* the text to hide start at 90px and end at 137px */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 90px 0, 90px 100%, 137px 100%, 137px 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Lorem ispum custom test</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64859070/7394871) от участника  [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Вы также можете использовать свой массив.

```js
var strings = [];
var str = document.getElementById("par");
if (str.textContent.includes("one")){
  var now = str.textContent.replace("one ", "");
  str.textContent = now;
  strings.push("one ")
};
console.log(strings)
```

```html
<p id="par">this one is changed</p>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64859311/7394871) от участника  [@hamid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11259304/hamid).</sub>